# Just a list of the imports for android

Tags: android, import

I am looking for a list, preferably in a text file, of all android imports. We're talking these things: `android.net.ConnectivityManager`

I know where to go look any one of them up in the references. But I need a list for a lightweight Android IDE I'm working on (see "pride" on freecode) (or not) (like I care).

Any ideas?

Comment: The later one, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I removed the other question: *And why is there a box underneath the "post your question" button here that says "answer your own question"? Then what? Read your own answer and comment on it?  I'm confused. Just help me find the list.* Check the comment above

Comment: So there's no sense of humor here I see. You professionals are soooo serious. Although, I note that the removed bit remains on the page. So perhaps there is a bit of humor?  Or at least irony?

Comment: My thanks to Zabri. That is perfect. Very kind of you to go to the trouble.

Comment: Poor Lukas. After the question has been answered and accepted, he closes the question as unreal and unanswerable. The answer, in fact, has already been used to implement import insertion in `pride`. (see freecode or Poor Richard's Alchemy.)  Again, my thanks to Zabri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Ok, I have done it for you. [Here you go](http://pastebin.com/ZAJP2nx7). :) And [here](http://pastebin.com/eEaxTuGf) is the used source code for you to check that there should really be everything (`classes.html` is the downloaded [website](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html)).

---

I wasn't able to find a textfile, but though I don't have any real experience with parsing websites, I think it shouldn't be that hard to parse it out from [this site](http://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html) which contains a list of all the classes you can use in / import into an Android project.

You may notice that the URL's of each of the class's documentation contain exatly what you need:

```
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html
```

If you remove `http://developer.android.com/reference/` from the beginning and `.html` from the end, and replace `/` with `.`, you're left with `android.net.ConnectivityManager`.

And as to finding all the URL's, you would have to search for this pattern in the HTML source code:

```
<td class="jd-linkcol">
    <a href="/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html">ConnectivityManager</a>
</td>
```

Let me know if you can manage to do it on your own, if not, I might try it and maybe learn something new. :)